# zendframework autoloading query

Tags: zend-framework, zend-autoloader

I am writing my own log class in zendframework based application. I was wondering as it's my own lib class where to keep it in application. I decided to keep this class parallel to "Zend" folder inside /library folder

```
-library
 - Zend
 - Helper [ custom lib classes]
```

In bootstrap.php I have _initAutoload function where in I have added following

```
  $autoloader=new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
            'namespace' => 'Demo',
        ));
        $autoloader->addResourceType('model', 'models/', 'Model');
        $autoloader->addResourceType('helper', APPLICATION_PATH.'/library/Helper', 'Helper');
```

but I get error Demo_Helper_Logger class not found.

Whats could be wrong here? Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Error is library is parallel to application and with some reason Zend_loader_Autoloader_Resources try n add the '/library/Helper' inside 'application' directory hence I am finding not found error. Anyone know how to autoload external library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ZF 1.9+ you can handle this inside your application.ini

Put your custom "library" into:

> ../library/Helper/Log.php

Name your class like:

```
class Helper_Log {}
```

Add

```
autoloadernamespaces.1 = "Helper_"
```

to your application.ini

```
$log = new Helper_Log();
```